# Передача данных во время выполнения PHP to Flex

Tags: php, json, xml, soap, apache-flex

Доброго времени суток. Появилась необходимость очень быстро разобраться в этом вопросе, собственно, вижу несколько приемлимых вариантов - XML, JSON, SOAP. Интересует следующее - каким образом `удобнее` писать и работать с сервером. Приоритет не скорость выполнения, а скорость и "легкость" написания и поддержки кода. Вообщем, что вы думаете по этому поводу, и что выбрали бы вы?

заранее благодарен...

Comment: что выполняется и куда передать? 

примерчик, если можно.

// т.е. я искренне надеюсь, что передать надо не переменные клиенту в процессе выполнения скрипта пхп, но все же)

Comment: Какая разница? Выполняется формирование данных приложения на основе овтета, манипулирование этими данными и т.д. и т.п.<br>
Вообщем типичное клиент-сервер RIA, если бы я уже написал примерчики то этого вопроса не было бы :)<br>
Перед тем как приступать мне надо все тщательно продумать, опыта написание RIA очень мало(читай нет), поэтому и спрашиваю.<br>

Comment: @Sh4dow кагбы переменную передать можнои и не только ее, более того можно напрямую вызывать методы того или иного серверного класса и т.д.<br>
Если вы не в теме то не надо умничать ;)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, конечно я не в теме)) Вообще я на php умею генерить мувиклипы, так что эти форматы мне не нужны ^`_`^ Но это коммерческая плюшка, поэтому тут ее светить не буду)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теоретически, использовать можно любой формат, но я бы остановился на `XML` или `JSON`, т.к `SOAP` все-таки идеологически относится к несколько другой сфере, да и поднимать `SOAP`-сервис - *это, предположительно, стрельба из пушки по воробьям и вряд ли будет способствовать простоте и удобочитаемости кода.*

А дальше, поскольку встроенные средства для работы с `XML` и `JSON` во флексе очень хороши, код должен получиться достаточно тривиальным. Выбор между этими форматами достаточно холиварен, могу посоветовать статью с хабра - http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/31225/

---

*В свое время мне пригодился вот этот пример (здесь правда серверная часть на `jsp`, но это несильно что-либо меняет) - http://www.infoq.com/articles/flex-xml-json*

Отмечу, что в моем случае взаимодействие было тривиальным - `php` цепляет данные из базы данных и генерит `xml`-ку в ответ на запрос из приложения на `ActionScript`. *Надо сказать, что проблем не было никаких и даже предположить не могу, где они могут здесь возникнуть.*

Comment: Проблема в том что с теоретической частью, да и, немного, с практической я знаком, то что сделать можно как угодно я вкурсе :)<br>
Меня интересует реальный практический совет, какой код будет легче в поддержке и расширении... Пока думаю о XML'e, JSON хоть и быстрый но при достаточном обьеме кода не всегда так легко и быстро разобратся что куда и зачем, в отличии от XML..<br>
По поводу SOAP - это вы зря, пускай код не будет таким коротким, но по опыту именно использовать SOAP сервер мегоудобно...<br>
Вообщем так и остался в раздумиях, пока пишу то в чем уверен на 100%

Comment: Я спрашиваю о том как лучше сделать с залогом на будущее, я где-то писал о проблемах написания?

Comment: @AlexWindHope Я бы не сильно заморачивался на этот счет. Это - один из немногих случаев, когда тратить время на написание кода, нежели размышление. В случае нормальной архитектуры проекта зарефакторить его и сменить, скажем, `xml` -> `json` должно быть достаточно тривиально *(при этом хорошая архитектура самого проекта - это как раз то, где стоит тратить время на размышление :)*